# Extract rows with upper limit by referring to another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe like this

```
code  Type  num
a    A     3  
a    A     4 
a    A     5
a    B     6
b    A     7
b    A     8
c    B     9
c    C     10
```

And I also have a  dataframe which represents the restricted code and Type and the upper limit of num with each code and Types.

```
code Type limit
a    A    4
b    A    7
c    C    11
```

So I would like to get the result below

```
code  Type  num
a    A     3  
a    A     4 
a    B     6
b    A     7
c    B     9
c    C     10
```

How can I select and extract rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go with `merge` followed by a `filter` process:

```
df.merge(df1, how="left")[lambda x: x.limit.isnull() | (x.num <= x.limit)].drop("limit", 1)

#code Type  num
#0  a    A    3
#1  a    A    4
#3  a    B    6 
#4  b    A    7
#6  c    B    9
#7  c    C   10
```

Comment: Thank you for cooperation ! I am wondering where is 'filter()' method in this code. How can I apply 'filter()' method?

Comment: It's not really using a `filter`. when I say `filter`, I refer to this part: `[lambda x: x.limit.isnull() | (x.num <= x.limit)]`, maybe it's better to call it boolean indexing, basically it allows you to write it in one line since you can refer to the previous result as a parameter in the lambda expression, i.e. `x` here.